# How do I write a loop that prints the year and balance?

Tags: java

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Starting Balance: ");
Double balance = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Yearly Contribution: ");
Double cont = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Average Return On Investment as %: ");
Double avg = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Number of years: ");
int year = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

double result1 = (balance + cont) * (1 + avg / 100);
double result2 = (result1 + cont) * (1 + avg / 100);

  year = 0;
    while (year <= year) {
        System.out.println("Year " + year + ": " + balance + "");
        year = year + 1;
        for (result2 = result2; result2 >= result2; result2 = result2 + result2) {
        }
```

//I am aware that the loop is wrong, just not sure the best way to write it.

Comment: I fixed your formatting, but I see no attempt at a loop (or attempt to print the balance); what research have you done? How have your attempts not worked? Where are they?

Comment: I have added my attempt on my loop.

Comment: When would `year` not be equal to `year`? Why did you reset it to `0`? When would `result2` not be equal to `result2`? Go read the documentation about `while` loops and `for` loops again.

Comment: I set year to equal zero because the assignment said the original balance entered has to be at Year 0: and so on.

Comment: You don't know what you want to loop and what the loop condition is. Please read the homework particularly.

Comment: The program should prompt for several input using the following prompts: Enter Starting Balance:
Enter Yearly Contribution:
Enter Average Return On Investment as %:
Enter Number of years:
The program should calculate the balance at the end of each year.

Sample input:
1000,
100,
5,
3

Sample Output:
Enter Starting Balance:
Enter Yearly Contribution:
Enter Average Return On Investment as %:
Enter Number of years:
Year 0: 1000.00,
     Year 1: 1155.00,
    Year 2: 1317.75,
    Year 3: 1488.64

Answer (score -1):

So provided there isn't a whole lot of detail, I wrote this code which results in output very close to the example you provided. Modify it as needed to match your desired output.

```
package various;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Balance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Starting Balance: ");
        double balance = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Yearly Contribution: ");
        double cont = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Average Return On Investment as %: ");
        double avg = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Number of years: ");
        int years = sc.nextInt();

        double temp = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= years; i++) {
            double result = balance + (i*cont)+ (i*temp*(avg/100));
            temp = result;
            System.out.println("Year "+i+": "+result);
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```